# Is it possible to return data before the end of the onCall function in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know if it's possible to return data before my onCall function finish.
Here is what I'm trying to do and my result data in my app is always equal to null:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth.uid) {
    return {
      statut: "NOK",
    };
  }

  return Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])
    .then(results => {
      const result1 = results[0].data();

      return FIRESTORE.collection('MyCollection')
        .add(result1)
        .then(results2 => {
          let queries = [];

          queries.push(
            function1234()
          );

          queries.push(
              FIRESTORE.collection('MyCollection2')
                .doc("123")
                .set({a: 123})
          );
          return Promise.all(queries)
            .then(r => {
              return { myReturn: "AAAA" };
            });

        })
        .then(r2 => {
          console.log('0000');
          return function9898();
        })
})
```

this is my client side function:

```
  myFunction = () => {
    var myFunctionCloud = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myFunction');
    myFunctionCloud().then(function (result) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    })
  }
```

My logs :

> {"data":null}

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if it's possible to return data before my onCall
>   function finish.

No, it is not possible since returning data in a Callable Cloud Function indicates to the Cloud Functions platform that the Callable Cloud Function is finished and that it can clean up everything from that invocation. So in many cases, your Cloud Function will be terminated before your business logic is fully executed.

In **some** cases, it **may be** possible that the Cloud Functions platform does not terminate your CF immediately, giving enough time for your business logic to be fully executed, but this is not at all guaranteed. Relying on this specific case is not recommended and actually leads to some "erratic" behaviour

---

One of the approach to immediately send back a result to the front-end and continue to work in the background is to call a [PubSub Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) (with all the relevant input in the message) and then return the value. In other words, you delegate the remaining work to another Cloud Function and you stop the current Callable one by returning a response.

Comment: @Joris Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed answer?